# Where is the operator ≣ defined?

Tags: agda, agda-stdlib

I am trying to write Agda program and struggle with package lookup for reference in the module import section.

As far as I know ≣ is produced from `\===`.

Grepping agda-library and agda-stdlib projects don't show anything:

```
grep -r -E  "===[^=]"  ./agda-stdlib/ ./agda-stdlib/src
```

```
module Hell3 where

open import Prelude
open import Reflection
--open import Equality
open import Builtin.Reflection
open import Container.List


example : (3 ^ 4) ≣ 81
example = refl 82
```

```
Not in scope:
  ≣ at /home/Hell3.agda:11,19-20
when scope checking ≣
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the ≡ symbol (\== or \equiv) instead? It is defined in `Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality`. I don't know of any part of the standard library that uses the `≣` symbol.

Comment: @Jesper, thx, though using ≡  instead causes the error: "(3 ^ 4) ≡ (3 ^ 4) should be a function type, but it isn't ..."

Answer (score -1):

Following snippet is correct.

```
module Hell3 where
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality  
open import Data.Nat  
example : 3 ^ 4 ≡ 81
example = refl
```

Thanks to Agda discord channel.
So my conclusion is that HoTTEST using custom definitions for standard API - refl doesn't take arguments and erefl should be used, and as noted in the comment here quadbar operator is actually triplebar one.